# Making a Pivot in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I am having some trouble making a pivot in oracle sql. I have a table with `workdate`, `employee` and their `shift` for a day. This table is called `SHIFT`.
I want that in this pivot, the workdate becomes the column headings, the employee become the row headings and the shifts be the day so you can see the employee shift per day.

My current problem is that i have a query but the pivot requires that i put an aggregate function. The query is as follows:

```
select employee, workdate, shift from shift
pivot (
        max(shift)
        for employee
        in (
            1,2,3,4
        )
)
```

SO i did this and it is bringing back all the columns and not in a pivoted format.
Current Strucutre:

| employee | workdate | shift |
| --- | --- | --- |
| employee1 | date1 | shift1 |
| employee1 | date2 | shift2 |
| employee2 | date1 | shift1 |
| employee2 | date2 | shift2 |
| employee3 | date1 | shift1 |
| employee3 | date2 | shift2 |
| employee4 | date1 | shift1 |
| employee4 | date2 | shift2 |
| employee5 | date1 | shift1 |
| employee5 | date2 | shift2 |

My desired results are:

|  | date1 | date2 | date3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| employee1 | shift1 | shift2 | shift3 |
| employee2 | shift1 | shift2 | shift3 |
| employee3 | shift1 | shift2 | shift3 |
| employee4 | shift1 | shift2 | shift3 |

Thanks you for your answers.

Comment: If you need to pivot by dates, then you need to specify `workdate` in `for` and dates in `in`

Comment: I want the workdae to run across and the employee to run down but the shift must be between as the data (shift per day) but i have to use an aggreate function in the pivot and it just produces the wrong results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```sql
select employee,
       date1,
       date2,
       date3
from   shift
pivot (
 max(shift)
 for workdate
 in (
   DATE '2021-08-17' AS date1,
   DATE '2021-08-18' AS date2,
   DATE '2021-08-19' AS date3
 )
)
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE shift (employee, workdate, shift) AS
SELECT 'employee1', DATE '2021-08-17', 'shift1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'employee1', DATE '2021-08-18', 'shift2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'employee2', DATE '2021-08-17', 'shift1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'employee2', DATE '2021-08-18', 'shift2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'employee3', DATE '2021-08-17', 'shift1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'employee3', DATE '2021-08-18', 'shift2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'employee4', DATE '2021-08-17', 'shift1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'employee4', DATE '2021-08-18', 'shift2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'employee5', DATE '2021-08-17', 'shift1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'employee5', DATE '2021-08-18', 'shift2' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | EMPLOYEE | DATE1 | DATE2 | DATE3 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | employee2 | shift1 | shift2 |  |
> | employee1 | shift1 | shift2 |  |
> | employee3 | shift1 | shift2 |  |
> | employee5 | shift1 | shift2 |  |
> | employee4 | shift1 | shift2 |  |

*Note: your data had zero rows for shift3.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=471a6e641e569005f122311b14ac6af5)*

Comment: This works but i also discovered that you can do the same pivot in an interactive report and add an LOV to the shift column and it worked how i wanted it to work

Answer (score 1):

If you need where clause on employee along with pivot on workdate then you will write

```
 SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT employee, workdate, shift 
        FROM shift WHERE employee IN ('employee1', 'employee2', 'employee3')
   )
   pivot (
       max(shift)
       for workdate
       in (
        ('date1','date2','date3','date4')
      )
  )
```

Comment: This works. Thank you. It is another way of doing the query